# Python: Import list from other module

Tags: python, python-import

If I import a list from another module, do I get a reference or a deep copy of that object?

So if I change it in the importing module, will it affect the variable in the module it got imported from?

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are mutable. So yes, changing it in the other file would change it in original as well. If you want a copy, you need to make it yourself.

```
import copy
from other_file import mylist

mylist = copy.deepcopy(mylist) # provided all objects are indeed "deep-copyable".
```

Comment: Just a note that the change only affects the __current python session__. If the variable is imported in another session then that session will start with a fresh version of that list