# Store dynamic variables in Django globally

Tags: python, django, websocket

How to store variables globally in Django, so I can access the variables from ALL Django files?
When declaring a variable as global in views.py for instance, it doesn't have the same memory in other files including routing.py>consumers.py. Note: I am using websockets and channels.

The variable to be stored is a list with classes (clients) with their individual socket connection (not websocket), so it is not possible to store it in a database.

I am making a webversion of a reverse shell. The victims/clients will then connect to the server and I will be able to send commands to them through the socket connection. It works perfectly fine in a regular terminal, as it is where I created the project in the beginning.

Does someone know how to do this?

```
all_clients = []
class Client():
    def __init__(self, clientSocket, name, ip, port, permission, time_when_connected):
        self.clientSocket = clientSocket
        self.name = name
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.permission = permission
        self.time_when_connected = time_when_connected
```

Comment: Why can't you write this variable to database? Have you considered sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?

Comment: @Someprogammer Does that work, so it is not just per visitor of the webpage? The data has to be consistent even though someone else visits the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your target module replace the list `all_clients` with a dictionary. Store all your clients within that as a reference:

```
clients = { 'all': [] }
# all_clients = []
```

The data persists through module imports when utilised from another module:

```
from client_app.views import clients #above object
all_clients = clients['all']
```

Due to the referencing within the python runtime this can't be sure to return *the true reference* of the "current" clients object, as such create afunction within the same module as the "clients" reference:

```
clients = { 'all': [] }
# all_clients = []

def get_all_clients():
    return clients['all']
```

You can apply some sibling functions to help:

```
def add_client(entity):
    clients['all'].append(entity)
```

within your *other* module, import and use the function:

```
from client_app.views import get_all_clients, add_client

c = Client()
add_client(c)
all_clients = get_all_clients()
assert c in all_clients
```

---

This is due to the object referencing of Lists, more can be understood here: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.

Lists are mutable, but due to the importing of the target module, the reference to the list may not yield the references of *the other module*: [Python: Import list from other module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689897/python-import-list-from-other-module)

However the above pattern works really well.